# Logging/Printing List of HashMap<String, dynamic> dart flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, logging, hashmap

I am having a **Future** that is `async` and returns a List of **HashMap<String, dynamic>** that I would like to log. I am using

Below is the Future

```
Future<List<HashMap<String, dynamic>>> _fetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonkeeper.com/b/XBCA"));
      final decodedJson = json.decode(response.body);

      final responseList = decodedJson.map<HashMap<String, dynamic>>((e) => HashMap<String, dynamic>.from(e)).toList();


      return responseList;

    } catch (e) {

      log("FetchUsersUsingListOfHashMapException $e");

      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Below is my initState where i am printing

```
@override
  void initState() {

    log("PrintFetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap $_fetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap()");


    super.initState();
  }
```

Below is how the list should look like when i am logging

```
[
    {
        "name": "Kamchatka",
        "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborumnumquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.",
        "email": "kamchatka@mail.com",
        "index": 1,
        "picture": "https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/"
    },
    {
        "name": "Valjakutse",
        "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborumnumquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.",
        "email": "valjakutse@mail.com",
        "index": 2,
        "picture": "https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/"
    },
    {
        "name": "Shipment",
        "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborumnumquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.",
        "email": "shipment@mail.com",
        "index": 3,
        "picture": "https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/"
    }
]
```

But when I am logging I am getting something like this below

```
PrintFetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap Closure: () => Future<List<HashMap<String, dynamic>>> from Function '_fetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap@20327479':.()
```

How can i be able to print the list  i have tried using print below but its return Closure

```
print("PrintFetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap $_fetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap()");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `_fetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap()` is `Future` and if you directly try to `print` it it will return you a `Instance of Future` not the `value` and to print the value you need to call another function using `async` and `await` to fetch the value from your Future function like and call that function in your `initState`.

```
void printData() async {
    log("PrintFetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap ${ await _fetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap()}");
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    printData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: It is still returning Instance of Future event when using printData()

Comment: Have you written your own code or pasted mine? It's printing the data check attached image .

Comment: oh i have seen where i have messed in my code

Comment: So now is it working?

Comment: yeah its working fine

Comment: It's good . Please mark it as answer as well. Thanks :)

Comment: what if am having a Future that returns a list of class and i am trying to log using your method but i am still getting Instance of the Future like this: [Instance of 'User', Instance of 'User', Instance of 'User'] and its not printing the values

Comment: Well in that case you have to print like this yourList[index].email;

Answer (score 1):

_fetchUsersUsingListOfHashMap is a future, consider using the `await` keyword before printing.

As a example:

```dart
var result = await someFutureFunction();

print('result: $result')
```

All that inside a async function.